# How to get a certain table tag from div tag inside of html?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the table information from the web-site http://www.o1vsk.lv/index.php/stundu-izmainas .[html content of the web-page i need to extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVrwB.png)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
html = urlopen("http://www.o1vsk.lv/index.php/stundu-izmainas").read()

rows=[]
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
box = soup.find('div', {'class': 'DRight'})
```

This program gets all content of the page, while I need only one little table in the text format like:

---

- [the table i need to get in the text format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPAnf.png) 6.d

1. ...
2. ...
3. ...
4. ...
5. ...
6. ...
7. ...
8. ...

Comment: .find(div..).find(table..) this works for me in most cases, so your perty much climbing the ladder down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution for you:

1. Find all the `table` tag and it will return HTML code

```py
table = box.findAll("table")
```

2. Convert the HTML to Pandas DataFrame (df). Why index = 1? Because the table you want in the index 1

```py
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[1]
```

3. Lastly, remove `Unnamed` column to get only the needed column

```py
df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.match('Unnamed')]
```

Here is the full code:

```py
from pandas import pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
html = urlopen("http://www.o1vsk.lv/index.php/stundu-izmainas").read()

rows=[]
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
box = soup.find('div', {'class': 'DRight'})

table = box.findAll("table")
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[1]

df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.match('Unnamed')]
```